# Open XML SDK - AddImagePart - Change image location from /media to /word/media

Tags: c#, image, openxml, google-drive-api, openxml-sdk

I am trying to insert an image into a document from C# using the Open XML SDK 2.5. The document is subsequently going to be uploaded to Google Drive and converted to a Google Document.

I am currently using the [MainDocumentPart.AddImagePart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc536156.aspx) method which inserts the image into the `/media` folder of the file hierarchy. However, Drive only wants to read the image if it is located in the `/word/media` folder.

Opening the document in Microsoft Word and saving it again relocates the image to the `/word/media` folder (and updates the part relationships), and thus makes Drive able to read the image, but the file is not going to be edited in Word before being uploaded to Drive.

Is there any way to place the image in the `/word/media` folder, short of closing the file in Open XML SDK, opening it up as a zip-archive, relocating the images and updating the relationships manually?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To add an image to the `/word/media` folder using the Open XML SDK 2.5
you have to create the package part for the image yourself. 
The `AddImagePart()` member function of the `MainDocumentPart` class 
always stores the image in the `/media` folder.

The code below shows how to insert an image into the `/word/media` folder
using the following steps:

1. Create a `PackagePart` with the path Uri set to `/word/media`.
2. Feed the image data into the package part.
3. Create a `PackageReleationship` for the image.
4. Use the ID of the `PackageReleationship` to reference the image in
    the word document.

I've copied the code for the `AddImageToBody()` function
from this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb497430.aspx) website.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  InsertAPicture("mydoc.docx", "mypic.jpg");      
}

public static void InsertAPicture(string document, string fileName)
{
  using (WordprocessingDocument wordprocessingDocument =
      WordprocessingDocument.Open(document, true))
  {
    MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart;

    Uri imageUri = new Uri("/word/media/" +
      System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName), UriKind.Relative);

    // Create "image" part in /word/media
    // Change content type for other image types.
    PackagePart packageImagePart = 
      wordprocessingDocument.Package.CreatePart(imageUri, "Image/jpeg");

    // Feed data.
    byte[] imageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
    packageImagePart.GetStream().Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

    PackagePart documentPackagePart = 
      mainPart.OpenXmlPackage.Package.GetPart(new Uri("/word/document.xml", UriKind.Relative));

    Console.Out.WriteLine(documentPackagePart.Uri);

    // URI to the image is relative to releationship document.
    PackageRelationship imageReleationshipPart = documentPackagePart.CreateRelationship(
          new Uri("media/" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName), UriKind.Relative),
          TargetMode.Internal, "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/image");

    AddImageToBody(wordprocessingDocument, imageReleationshipPart.Id);
  }
}

private static void AddImageToBody(WordprocessingDocument wordDoc, string relationshipId)
{
  var element =
       new Drawing(
           new DW.Inline(
               new DW.Extent() { Cx = 990000L, Cy = 792000L },
               new DW.EffectExtent()
               {
                 LeftEdge = 0L,
                 TopEdge = 0L,
                 RightEdge = 0L,
                 BottomEdge = 0L
               },
               new DW.DocProperties()
               {
                 Id = (UInt32Value)1U,
                 Name = "Picture 1"
               },
               new DW.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties(
                   new A.GraphicFrameLocks() { NoChangeAspect = true }),
               new A.Graphic(
                   new A.GraphicData(
                       new PIC.Picture(
                           new PIC.NonVisualPictureProperties(
                               new PIC.NonVisualDrawingProperties()
                               {
                                 Id = (UInt32Value)0U,
                                 Name = "New Bitmap Image.jpg"
                               },
                               new PIC.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties()),
                           new PIC.BlipFill(
                               new A.Blip(
                                   new A.BlipExtensionList(
                                       new A.BlipExtension()
                                       {
                                         Uri =
                                           "{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}"
                                       })
                               )
                               {
                                 Embed = relationshipId,
                                 CompressionState =
                                 A.BlipCompressionValues.Print
                               },
                               new A.Stretch(
                                   new A.FillRectangle())),
                           new PIC.ShapeProperties(
                               new A.Transform2D(
                                   new A.Offset() { X = 0L, Y = 0L },
                                   new A.Extents() { Cx = 990000L, Cy = 792000L }),
                               new A.PresetGeometry(
                                   new A.AdjustValueList()
                               ) { Preset = A.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle }))
                   ) { Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" })
           )
           {
             DistanceFromTop = (UInt32Value)0U,
             DistanceFromBottom = (UInt32Value)0U,
             DistanceFromLeft = (UInt32Value)0U,
             DistanceFromRight = (UInt32Value)0U,
             EditId = "50D07946"
           });

  wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.AppendChild(
    new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph(
      new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run(element)));
}
```

Of course, if you want to add other image types (e.g. PNG) you have to change the
the content type.

Comment: Thank you very much - it works admirably. It isn't as pretty as a call to AddImagePart, but it sure beats the open-as-a-zip method.

Comment: Thanks so much for this solution. This solved a mailing problem for me, where the OpenXML generated attachment of an email caused it to disappear into the void. After applying this fix, the mail with docx attachment is sent succesfully.